# How to get source range of AST nodes using megaparsec?

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I'm trying to generate a source map for some source file I'm parsing and I want to get the range for each node. [getSourcePos](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-8.0.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html) only gives the [start position](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-8.0.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Pos.html#t:SourcePos) of a node (src:line:column). How to get its end position?

Comment: You would need to look at the start position of the next node.

Comment: Yes, the key is to identify where is the next node. If there's a right sibling, that's easy. What if the node itself has no right sibling?

Comment: You will have to traverse the tree, going up.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I want to see if there is library doing this before implementation. Seems like a common functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to construct a source span like this for each lexeme:

```
data Span = Span SourcePos SourcePos

data Spanned a = Spanned Span a
```

You can just call `getSourcePos` twice, once at the beginning of a token and once at the end, before consuming any whitespace, assuming you’re at the lexing stage. I’ve used a structure like this in the past to make this more convenient:

```
-- Augment a parser with a source span.
spanned :: Parser (a, SourcePos) -> Parser (Spanned a)
spanned parser = do
  start <- getSourcePos
  (x, end) <- parser
  pure (Spanned (Span start end) x)

-- Consume whitespace following a lexeme, but record
-- its endpoint as being before the whitespace.
lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser (a, SourcePos)
lexeme parser = (,) <$> parser <*> (getSourcePos <* whitespace)
```

Bearing in mind that `getSourcePos` is somewhat costly, per the documentation, and if I recall correctly this depends on source file size.

If an AST is annotated with spans, you can compute the span of any part of the tree by folding over it with a monoid instance for `Span` that takes their union (or more specifically their bounding box), i.e. `a <> b` is a span from `` (beginRow a, beginCol a) `min` (beginRow b, beginCol b) `` to `` (endRow a, endCol a) `max` (endRow b, endCol b) ``.

Comment: This solution can work, but it requires me change lots of code using lexeme. I ended up saving the SourcePos before whitespace https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ecy3oa/how_to_get_source_range_of_ast_nodes_using/fc0zsb1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x